# MatLab Quadratic Equation With ln

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How to solve the function `f(x)=ln(x^2)-0.7=0` with a known Matlab command?

```
clc;clear all;close all;

f(x)=ln(x^2)-0.7=0
B=sqrt f(x)
```

Comment: how about `x = sqrt(exp(0.7));`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [symbolic variables](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-variables-expressions-and-functions.html) together with the [solve](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) function:

```
syms x;
eqn = log(x^2) - 0.7 == 0;
solve(eqn,x)
```

The above code will output:

```
ans =

  exp(7/20)
 -exp(7/20)
```

Since the equation is quadratic, the solver returns two distinct solutions (often people forget that quadratic equations may have two specular solutions, one positive and one negative).

If you want to retrieve the numerical values (for example, in order to calculate their `sqrt` value):

```
sol = solve(eqn,x);
num = double(sol)

num =

 1.4191
-1.4191
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code into a MATLAB script, name it "main.m".

```
function b=main
    clc
    x=solveF()
    y=f(x)
    b=sqrt(y)
end

function y=f(x)
    y=log(x^2)-0.7
end

function x=solveF()
    g = @(x) abs(f(x)-0)
    x = fminsearch(g, 1.0)
end
```

Then run it as:

```
main
```

You will get the results:

```
x =

     1.4190


y =

   -3.4643e-05


b =

    0.0000 + 0.0059i


ans =

    0.0000 + 0.0059i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define equations in matlab as such:

```
f = @(x) log(x^2)-0.7;
B = @(x) sqrt(f(x));
```

If you want to find the value of `x` satisfying a constraint you can design a function that will be equal to zero when the constraint is respecte, then call [fminsearch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to find `x`:

```
f_constraint = @(x) abs(f(x)-0);
x_opt = fminsearch(f_constraint, 1.3); % function handle, initial estimate
```

In your example, `B(x_opt)` should be equal to zero. This is not exactly the case as fminsearch estimated a solution.